# More efficient way to find object in List<object>

Tags: c#, .net, list

Assume that `arrRowLength`&`arrColLength` have all been properly defined and assigned, and `MyObjectList<MyObject>` has been instantiated and populated with a few objects.

```
class MyObject
{
    public MyObject() { }
    public int rowIndex {get; set;}
    public int colIndex {get; set;}
} 

List<MyObject> MyObjectList = new List<MyObject>();

for (int r = 1; r <= arrRowLength; r++)
{
    for (int c = 1; c <= arrColLength; c++)
    {
         MyObject mo = MyObjectList.Find(item => (item.rowIndex == r && item.colIndex == c));
         if(mo != null)
         {
              //found, do sth...
         }
    }
}
```

Above is my current approach to finding a `MyObject` object from `MyObjectList`, where `rowIndex` and `colIndex` equal to `r` and `c` in for loops.

However, `Find()` has **O(n)** complexity. The larger the MyObjectList gets, the longer it takes. So I wonder if there's a **better / more efficient way** to find the object. How can I implement this with `.BinarySearch()` method?

Comment: `MyObjectList` is `List<MyObject>`?

Comment: Does MyObjectList have to be a List? You could try a Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,MyObject> where the tuple is of row and column index?

Comment: I can not understand the function of this code section. If arrRowLength and arrColLength is large enough, it will select all objects inside from the list?

Comment: To use a binary search you'd have to sort your list with a comparison method that compared by row and then by index (or vice-versa), and then use that same comparison method when searching. Alternatively you could use implement GetHashCode() for MyObject so that it uses rowIndex and colIndex in its computation, and then use a hashed container such as a Dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your real requirements, but choosing more appropriate data structures could be one approach.

One example would be a Dictionary with a `Tuple<int, int>` as the key, where the first item is the row index and the second item is the column index. "Search" would now be a lookup and O(1):

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, MyObject> MyObjects;
MyObject o;
if(MyObjects.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create(r, s), out o)
{
    //found, do sth...
}
```

Adding a new object to the dictionary would look like this:

```
MyObjects.Add(Tuple.Create(o.rowIndex, o.colIndex), o);
```

If - for some reason - you would need to iterate all objects in another method, you can still do this using the `Values` property of the dictionary:

```
foreach(var o in MyObjects.Values)
{
    // do something for each of your objects.
}
```

Comment: Never thought of using Dictonary<Tuple<int, int>, MyOjbect> data structure. I will give it a try in my code. Many thanks for bringing up new ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SortedList<>` with its method [`IndexOfKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.indexofkey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which uses a binary search.

It returns the zero-based index of the key parameter, if key is found in the `SortedList object; otherwise, -1.`

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Another way to reduce number of iterations:

1. Sort `MyObjectList`: by rowIndex Asc -> by colIndex Asc
2. Iterate `MyObjectList` with `foreach` loop until `rowIndex` is equal to `arrRowLength`

This approach eliminates neccessity of iterating wh0le  2d-matrix + reduces number of visited instances in `List<MyObject>`

Answer (score 0):

Another idea - for cases when you need to find only specific row (or column) and not the cell you can use Lookup class:

```
Lookup<int, MyObject> rowIndex = MyObjectList.ToLookup(o => o.rowIndex, o => o);
```

having this you can quickly retrieve all cells of given row i by simply referencing:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> rowCells = rowIndex[i];
```